# How to use gitlab ci to test if a java maven project can be built and run under multiple jdks platform?

Tags: automated-tests, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In some other ci, for example, with Travis, it supports multiple JDKs test (e.g https://blog.travis-ci.com/support_for_multiple_jdks).

However, I'm not sure how can I make it under the GitLab ci.

Assume I have a java project, I want to make sure this project can both build and run correctly under jdk8 and jdk11, How can I do this in the Gitlab CI?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to define pipeline jobs with different images with required dependencies. You can use any public images from `dockerhub`. After quick search I choose for my yaml example `codenvy/jdk8_maven3_tomcat8` (jdk8 + maven) and `appinair/jdk11-maven` (jdk11 + maven), I'm not sure they will work for you though.

```yaml
tests_jdk8:
    image: codenvy/jdk8_maven3_tomcat8
    script:
      - <your mvn test/build script>
tests_jdk11:
    image: appinair/jdk11-maven
    script:
      - <your mvn test/build script>
```

If you can dockerize your environment you can use your custom images instead. Or you write some `before_script` which can install your project requirements to any os docker image. Would be perfect to reflect existing production environment.

If you have already instances where you test your project you can always connect them as Gitlab shell/docker runner and run your test on custom runner.

All depends on what resources you've got and what do you want to achieve.